# How to style dynamically in Reactjs (responvie, media-query, mobile version)

Tags: reactjs, components

I have a Button component. Since padding for the button can be different, I want it to be dynamic.

Please check the component.

```
const Button = ({children, padding="0.5rem"}) => {
   return(
      <button
         className={...}
         style={{ padding, ..style, ...dynamicStyle }}
         {...rest}>
         {children}
      </button>
   )
}
```

So, What I've done is setting a default padding which is 0.5rem and Whenever I set different value of padding on other components, I do something like this.

```
<Button padding="1.5rem 5rem" type="submit">Button</Button>
```

However, I wanna change the padding again when the user is on mobile.
(=When the width is smaller than certain size)
Is there any good idea to solve this? Of course, I can add class to custom the padding but its too much I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this

```
style={{height: this.props.width >= 1200 ? 'calc(100vh - 200px)' : 'calc(100vh - 80px)'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't implement media queries with inline styling. There may be some packages which allow you to do this but it is not efficient. I suggest you to set up CSS modules and create CSS files for every component.

Here's [a link](https://medium.com/@dannyhuang_75970/how-to-setup-css-modules-in-create-react-app-a03b65e14746) for the setup.

Answer (score 0):

if you have jquery use like this

```
var width=$(window).width();
var padding="0.5rem";
if(width && width<767 ){
//checking if  window object is available or not and checking mobile width 
padding="1.5rem";
}
```

`<Button padding={{"padding":padding}} type="submit">Button</Button>`

Hope this works good luck